# Ionic - How to execute a function only after an update has been made

Tags: ionic-framework, updates

Does anyone know how to execute a function only after an update using Ionic Framework?

The situation is as follow: My app is already on the store. I want to make an update. After that update I want a function to execute when the user opens the app for the first time after the update. How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: If your application is working with internet so you can do it like create one table in web server and set fields like userid and is_updated. after open your application you have to set this flag as true and you have to check it every time is it true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after? Probably best to put it into your app's run() function:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (!window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty('functionExecuted')){
        //Place your code here

        window.localStorage['functionExecuted'] = true;
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works! Can you explain what this line does: !window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty('functionExecuted')

Comment: It checks whether localStorage contains a property called 'functionExecuted'. As this property is set only in the if block, it will be executed only once, when the application is executed for the first time. For more information regarding localStorage please see http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful!